# Can I document multiple constants in a single line?

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm documenting a module which exposes a set of opaque constant sentinel values, representing the different possible states of a state machine.

There really isn't anything interesting to say about each one of them in isolation. Currently my docs look like:

```
[... state machine diagram ...] [... high level explanation ...]
States are represented using one of the following constants:

.. data:: IDLE
.. data:: SEND_RESPONSE
.. data:: SEND_BODY
[and so on for another 10 lines]
```

The good thing about making a `.. data::` entry for each constant is that it means that later I can hyperlink back to these docs by writing things like

```
If the connection is in the :data:`IDLE` state...
```

and they show up in the index, and so forth. The bad thing is that each of those constants gets a big bold paragraph just to itself, so the whole list ends up taking like an entire screenful of the rendered docs with basically no content.

I'd like to somehow just list these on a single line ("One of the following constants: `IDLE`, `SEND_RESPONSE`, ..."), or even leave the list out altogether ("For each of the states named in the above diagram, there is a corresponding module-level constant ..."), and yet have sphinx's indexing and cross-linking still work.

Maybe there's some way I can tell sphinx "hey psst, you don't need to render anything here but just FYI this paragraph documents the following data items"? Or any other ideas for how to reduce the clutter here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! You can write:

```
.. data:: IDLE
          SEND_RESPONSE
          SEND_BODY
          ...
```

and at least in the readthedocs theme it will render like this:

[image: example rendering]